# Prevent caching of select List selected items on Mozilla 10.0.2

Tags: html, browser-cache

I have a functionality on one of my web pages where a select box is pre-selected when the user goes on the page and accordingly the page is populated i.e dependent on the select box selected item value.

Now on Mozilla 10.0.2 when we change the select box value my functionality works.But when we do an F5 on the page the pre-selected value is not selected but the data is populated according to it.

This happens on Mozilla 10.0.2 and I.E 9 it works fine on Chrome 17.
I do not wish to add the html meta tag for no cache as I want the page's images and all to be cached but not this select box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try *autocomplete="off"* in select